# Google Sheet : Query Date is Today Problem

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a data in Sheet1 with Col is A, B, C which C is date format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, I need to query the data in Sheet1 where C is today date. My formula is

`=query('Sheet1!A1:C',"Select * where C = Date'"&text(today(),"YYYY-MM-DD")&"')`

But result return is empty even C is today date.

When I change the formula to this format then it works,

`=query('Sheet1!A1:C',"Select * where C < Date'"&text(today()-1,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"'and C > Date'"&text(today()+1,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"')`

I wonder what was wrong with my first formula when I use "=" in the query.

Thanks

Comment: Can you maybe share a copy of your spreadsheet so we can have a closer look?

Comment: What format does the `A1:C` range have? Moreover, can you share a copy of your sheet as well? @TuPHAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first formula never does any manipulation on C:C. This means that the equality filter only matches when the time is also `0:00:00` of the same day. You can use the `toDate` Query function to convert C like so:

```
=query(A1:C,"Select * where toDate(C) = Date'"&text(today(),"YYYY-MM-DD")&"'")
```

See the doc on [scalar functions](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#scalar-functions) for documentation.